How Did the the story of the Miracle of Hanukkah arise? 2 Macc. 10
Jews have long marked the day by lighting candles for each of the days that the holy oil for the Temple menorah miraculously lasted.  Yet the scriptural account of event (accepted as an inspired text by Catholics but not by Jews or Protestants) does not mention the miracle of the oil.

1 When Maccabeus and his companions, under the Lord’s leadership, had
recovered the temple and the city, 2 they destroyed the altars erected
by the foreigners in the marketplace and the sacred shrines. 3 After
purifying the temple, they made another altar. Then, with fire struck
from flint, they offered sacrifice for the first time in two years,
burned incense, and lighted lamps... 5 On the
anniversary of the day on which the temple had been profaned by the
foreigners, that is, the twenty-fifth of the same month Kislev, the
purification of the temple took place. 6 The Jews celebrated joyfully
for eight days as on the feast of Booths...7 Carrying rods entwined with
leaves, beautiful branches and palms, they sang hymns of grateful
praise to him who had successfully brought about the purification of
his own place. 8 By public decree and vote they prescribed that the
whole Jewish nation should celebrate these days every year.

Question: how did this account evolve into the tradition that God caused the holy oil (enough for one day only) to last for eight days?

I don't know enough to give a real answer, but in case it helps anyone else, two early records of the miracle are:
Megillat Ta'anit, Kislev 8, First century;
and Megillat Antiochus 69, Second century.

"Evolve" Are you looking for intermediate stages? Most people will either tell you the oil story was known earlier and just wasn't bothered to be recorded by the author of Maccabees for whatever reason or that it was made up later to match the practice of lighting candles. But I don't know what kind of evolution you seek.

The book of Maccabees was written around 100 BC, what does Jesus or the Church have to do with your question?

@DoubleAA - Yes, I'm interested in how we get from 2 Macc., which does not tell of a miracle, to the Talmudic references mentioned by Ray Butterworth above

@CandidMoe the question was not asked here. I took out the NT refs,

@Shmuel I don't think the question should have been migrated here in the first place. It plowed new territory on BH.se but not here.

@RayButterworth Since Jesus prophesised the destruction of the Temple, I cannot personally discern how Hanukkah (which marks the rededication of the Temple in Jerusalem in the 2nd century BC, after a small group of Jewish fighters liberated it from occupying foreign forces) is related to Christmas or to Christianity; as at least is currently being heavily pushed in my country.
